# Different performance of query run against two tables with the same data

Tags: postgresql

#### BACKGROUND

Currently I have a **postgres** database with around 100 tables in the public schema. The performance of one of the large tables (around 4 million) was quite slow when upserting data to it (insert with conflict). When I created a like for like copy of the table (same table schema) in a different schema within the same database the upsert query performance significantly increased (6 minutes to under 3).

#### CODE USED

To create the tables (key is a basic hash):

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
    id SERIAL,
    ...,
    key CHARACTER VARYING,
    CONSTRAINT primary_key_constraint PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT key_uniqueness_constraint UNIQUE (key)
);
```

To upload the data to a dummy table using the same schema as *test_table* for upsert:

```
COPY dummy_table(
    ...,
    key
)
FROM '<path-to-csv>' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

To upsert data:

```
INSERT INTO test_table(
    ...,
    key
)
SELECT
    ...,
    key
FROM
    dummy_table
ON CONFLICT(key)
DO UPDATE SET
    ... = "some-change"
```

In order to actually test an upsert with conflict I insert half the data from *dummy_table* into *test_table*, followed by the rest once the query has finished.

#### CONSIDERATIONS

- `VACUUM FULL` and `VACUUM ANALYZE` was run on the public schema with 100 tables before the tests
- The database has also been reindexed prior to the tests
- `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` gives two identical query plans, except one runs much slower

NOTES: 
- all tables in the database, bar the test ones in the new schema, are within the public schema
- [UPDATE] I realise now that the existing table was heavily upserted into before the tests were carried out. The data in both tables was still exactly the same.

#### EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) OUTPUT

```
Insert on test_table  (cost=0.00..189096.00 rows=4000000 width=221) (actual time=1228323.809..1228323.809 rows=0 loops=1)
  Conflict Resolution: UPDATE
  Conflict Arbiter Indexes: key_uniqueness_constraint
  Tuples Inserted: 0
  Conflicting Tuples: 4000000
  Buffers: shared hit=69229375 read=3940270 dirtied=3756690 written=3290015
  ->  Seq Scan on all_data  (cost=0.00..189096.00 rows=4000000 width=221) (actual time=76.951..15397.431 rows=4000000 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=4000008 read=129100 dirtied=19 written=3
Planning Time: 157.181 ms
Execution Time: 1228335.801 ms
```

```
Insert on test_table  (cost=0.00..189033.00 rows=4000000 width=221) (actual time=260305.406..260305.406 rows=0 loops=1)
  Conflict Resolution: UPDATE
  Conflict Arbiter Indexes: key_uniqueness_constraint
  Tuples Inserted: 0
  Conflicting Tuples: 4000000
  Buffers: shared hit=72766787 read=560868 dirtied=431829 written=265784
  ->  Seq Scan on all_data  (cost=0.00..189033.00 rows=4000000 width=221) (actual time=44.326..15560.603 rows=4000000 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=4000008 read=129036 dirtied=8
Planning Time: 88.202 ms
Execution Time: 260312.309 ms
```

#### TL;DNR

Table upsert performance was bad within the public schema, shifted the table to a brand new schema within the same database and the performance significantly increased.

Comment: As always with such questions, no deal without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for both queries.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe apologies. I've updated my question to include the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) output

Comment: I find the planning time of 157ms (or even 88ms) way to high for such a simple statement. What is your exact Postgres version?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 11.2

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the execution plans don't offer many clues as to the `UPDATE`. Fact is that most of the time is spent updating. What sticks out is the huge number of blocks: is the table quite bloated, or did you define it with a small `fillfactor`, or are there very many columns? Since you say that the table definitions are identical, could you dump them with a `pg_dump -s -t <tablename> <dbname>` and check for differences?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thank you so much for your help! I checked the `pg_dump` and unfortunately they were both the same. I decided to drop and recreate the tables with the same `fillfactor` and it seemed to solve the issue?

The tables themselves had the same number of rows (4 million) and the same number of columns (10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If changing the `fillfactor` helped, which is what I read out of your comment, then it must be PostgreSQL “*write amplification*” problem:

- every update writes a new version of the row
- consequently, every index on the table must get a new entry pointing to the new row as well, which causes more writes and worse performance than in other databases

The remedy is to

- lower the fillfactor and
- make sure that no modified column is indexed

Then PostgreSQL can use HOT (“heap only tuple”) updates, which “redirect” from the original *item pointer* to the new row version and so avoid modifying the index at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! 

You've hit the nail on the head with regards to the problem diagnosis. I've used `cluster` on the table in production where this problem was occurring and that has brought the performance in line with what it should be. Your suggestion of `fillfactor` will hopefully make it so the performance doesn't degrade.